# Regular Expression to allow @

Tags: php, regex, magento, zend-framework

I have a regular expression check in Magento (php) that allows letters, digits and `_-`

here is the code

```
$validate = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^[\w-]*$/');
```

I am trying to get this to also allow the @ symbol, and as I probably find out, this would need a full rewrite of the regex, which I am no good at, can anyone help me find the correct Regexp

Comment: Seems like you want to require certain letters first. Maybe more info about the structure of the regex is needed.

Comment: It presently allows characters, numbers and _ and disallows everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
/^[\w@-]+$/
```

Comment: works fine, thanks a lot I will accept as soon as 10 mins condition is met